# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 - ui-mini overridden by theme css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-specificity

I'm updating a site from JQM 1.2.1 to 1.4.5, and I can't seem to get buttons to apply the styles for the class ui-mini with the dependencies in the proper order (as far as I'm aware).

```
//default JQM CSS:
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

//custom theme from ThemeRoller:
<link href="https://dev.domain.com/css/themes_145/theme_145.min.css" />

//JQuery and JQM JS:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Keeping things simple as can be, just the barebones CDN files and my custom theme above, and a page div with a single button inside:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<a class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-icon-arrow-r ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left">BUTTON</a>
</div>
```

Upon inspection, I see that the reduced font sizes and padding afforded by the ui-mini class are being overridden by the custom theme css, which is weird since, if I move the theme css before the JQM css, the theme itself is overridden (as I would have expected), but in any other case the ui-mini styles are not applied. The custom theme is freshly downloaded from Themeroller.

Am I misusing the custom theme somehow?  This setup worked like a charm in 1.2.1, and I'm not seeing how that particular part has changed in this version.

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/wm73pqq4/6/)

I'm stumped here. Anyone see where I've got it wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing that, according to this conversation: 

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/upgrading-jquery-mobile-1-2-0-to-1-4-5

That you're not meant to lead both the JQM CSS and the theme... but JQM does not work with only the theme css. This is the behavior I've come to expect from 1.2.1 (the theme was used for color schemes and visual presentation only, not things like font size – I don't even see an option for that in ThemeRoller), so I'm not sure that assertion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had the structure entirely wrong. Had to go back to the instructions on themeroller and load the structure and icon pack separately.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```